# How to rerender in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This code is working fine but I must change a state to show it on the table I'm using.

The code is:

```
 this.state.tableData=[]

        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.cityTable.length; i += 1) {
            let rowData = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < 7; j += 1) {
                switch (j) {
                    case 0: //draw cities rows
                        rowData.push(this.state.cityTable[i])
                        break;
                    case 1:  //num of candidate total
                        this.dbRef.where('Destination', '==', this.state.delegation)
                            .where('Location', '==', this.state.cityTable[i])
                            .get()
                            .then(querySnapshot => {
                                rowData.push(querySnapshot.size)
                            });
                        break;
                    case 2: //num of candidate
                        this.dbRef.where('Destination', '==', this.state.delegation)
                            .where('Location', '==', this.state.cityTable[i])

                            .get()
                            .then(querySnapshot => {
                                rowData.push(querySnapshot.size)
                            });
                        break;

                }
            }


            this.state.tableData.push(rowData);

        }
```

It is working but I know I must put some setState or make some force render. I call this method on render inside OnPress button - it has a picker to change values so can generate reports to that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need if you want to replace the items in tableData:

```
this.setState({tableData: rowData})
```

If you want to append to the items in tableData,

```
this.setState({tableData: [...this.state.tableData, ...rowData})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, where do I put that? after the push to array?
I tried to put there but gave me some error

Comment: `TypeError: data.map is not a function`

Comment: Move `let rowData=[ ]` above the for loop and  try `this.setState({tableData: rowData})` outside both the for loop

Comment: indeed for each col per loop iteration